# CSS Animation overlaps the text

Tags: html, css, animation, layer

(I'm not english. Hope you understand.)

Hi,
I need the animated div not to overlap the text.

```
<span>TEXT</span>
<div></div>
```

```
div {
   width: 10000px;
   height: 10000px;
   background: red;
   animation: div 5s linear infinite;
   position:relative;
}

@keyframes div{
   0%   {top: 0%; left: 0%;}
   50%   {top: 0%; left: 100%;}
   100% {top: 0%; left: 0%;}
}

span {
   font-size:50px;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Thanks for answers, Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text hover the div you can set on the text element a bigger z-index than the div.

```
div { z-index: 1 }

span { z-index: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index` for `span` in the CSS, it helps to specify the stack order of an element or the layer.
[image]
**Code Sample:**

```
span {
   font-size:50px;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
}
```

**Full code:**

```css
div {
   width: 10000px;
   height: 10000px;
   background: red;
   animation: div 5s linear infinite;
   position:relative;
}

@keyframes div{
   0%   {top: 0%; left: 0%;}
   50%   {top: 0%; left: 100%;}
   100% {top: 0%; left: 0%;}
}

span {
   font-size:50px;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<span>TEXT</span>
<div></div>
```